# How to sum values in an iteration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have the array `$scope.otherDetailsData`

```
[0] object 
amount: 29.9
code: "012"
currency: "BRL"
payedDate: "2016-11-10"
roDate: "2016-08-01"
type:"OTHER"

[1] object
amount: 39.9
code: "013"
currency: "BRL"
payedDate: "2016-11-11"
roDate: "2016-08-01"
type:"OTHER"
```

My problem is, how can I sum the amounts to have a variable with the total ?
eg: 69.8

```
<span> {{ totalOfSumAmount }} </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and most efficient) way is to just write a function that does this for you.

```
<span> {{ getTotalOfSumAmount() }} </span>
```

Add the function to your controller:

```
$scope.getTotalOfSumAmount = function () {
    var runningTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.otherDetailsData.length; i++) {
        runningTotal += $scope.otherDetailsData[i].amount;
    }
    return runningTotal;
}
```

Comment: Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: 
  {{ getTotalOfSumAmount() }}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
$scope.totalOfSumAmount = $scope.otherDetailsData.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev + curr.amount;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum the results. For example:

```
    $scope.totalOfSumAmount =   $scope.items.reduce(function(carry, currentItem) {
      //add the amount from the current item to the running total (carry)
      return carry + currentItem.amount;
    }, 0);//0 is the initial value
```

That call back function (i.e. `function(carry, currentItem) {...` in the example) actually can accept four parameters:

- previous value - the value from the previous iteration (or the initial value)
- current value - the current element in the array
- current index - the current index of the current element in the array
- original array - the array we are iterating over

And the second parameter (optional) is the initial value, so if, for example, we needed to start with 10, we could pass that instead of 0.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      amount: 29.9,
      code: "012",
      currency: "BRL",
      payedDate: "2016-11-10",
      roDate: "2016-08-01",
      type: "OTHER"
    }, {
      amount: 39.9,
      code: "013",
      currency: "BRL",
      payedDate: "2016-11-11",
      roDate: "2016-08-01",
      type: "OTHER",
    }];
    $scope.totalOfSumAmount =   $scope.items.reduce(function(carry, currentItem) {
      //add the amount from the current item to the running total (carry)
      return carry + currentItem.amount;
    }, 0);//0 is the initial value
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
Total: <span> {{ totalOfSumAmount }} </span>
  </div>
```